# How to check if value exists in other sheet, then output value from another cell in the row

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely stumped here and don't know the proper spreadsheet terminology.

So I have one sheet which has the following three columns

- Comment ID
- Comment Post ID
- Comment

Now the post ID refers to the ID of the post the comment was created on.

I have a second sheet (in the same workbook) that has the following columns:

- Post ID
- Post Title

How can I run a formula that makes Excel replace the values in 'Comment Post ID' with the correlating titles?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at VLookup

Comment: This is what Excel programmers do and charge for it. I suggest you google and experiment with variants of the Lookup function:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LOOKUP-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb
-
https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the Comment items are on `Sheet 1 columns A:C` and the Post items are on `Sheet 2 columns A:B`, in order, with headers.

In `Sheet 1 column D Row 2` use

`=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`

You can drag that down as far as your data goes and it will lookup the Comment Post ID from `Sheet 1 column B` to find the matching title in `Sheet 2 Column B`.

If you really want to replace your Comment Post ID column with the titles then just copy and paste the values of your new column D